wp plugin that call a api webpage works properly on iframe but not when same webpage displayed in modal/page
I am creating a custom wordpress plugin that embeds a webpage, but if the webpage is displayed in iframe everything works fine not when  it is displayed in modal or a page, the slider within the webpage do not work.
It is possibly because in iframe all js files are sourced and binded from stratch whereas in other element like div/ modal the elements are loaded asynchronously and might conflict with the main web js files. I have used settimeout so that the js functions are binded after all elements are loaded. And checked if the js/jquery files are being called properly in correct order, still the slider do not work
